# What is workingDirectory in Maven POM.xml?

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

Want to understand what and why  tag is used in Maven POM.xml. What is the significance of the tag?

Example:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <workingDirectory>target/</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Could you show example of your pom? It may be specific option for plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately such tag `workDirectory` does not exist in the pom file: https://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Comment: Added an example where it is used.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find something like `workingDirectory` in Maven Compiler plugin documentation as well? https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html  Where have you found that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `workingDirectory` element in the Maven POM by default, see [Maven POM reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) for details about the element you can use in your POM.

However, `workingDirectory` can exists in certain plugin configuration such as the `exec:exec` goal on the [Maven Exec Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html), for example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <executable>java</executable>
      <workingDirectory>target/</workingDirectory>
      <arguments>
        <argument>-classpath</argument>
        <classpath>
          <dependency>commons-io:commons-io</dependency>
          <dependency>commons-lang:commons-lang</dependency>
        </classpath>
        <argument>com.example.Main</argument>
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Would execute `java` from the `target` directory. However, adding a `workingDirectory` in the Compiler plugin as in your example won't do anything - there is no such configuration.